# Thymeleaf and spring - pagination for table?

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, thymeleaf, dandelion

I am developing one spring-boot application. I have to print Hashmap resultset as a table. For that I have created table using thymeleaf. The table has sometimes over 100k records. I want pagination for this table every 10 or 50 records.

My html using thymeleaf code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
  xmlns:dt="http://www.thymeleaf.org/dandelion/datatables">
<head lang="en">
 .
 .
<div id="myDivTable">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="bomTable" id="bomTable" 
 dt:table="true"  dt:displaylength="10">
    <span th:each="row, iter : ${result}" pages:paginate="5">
        <tr th:classappend="${iter.first} ? header-style">
            <span th:each="cell : ${row.value}">
            <td th:classappend="${#strings.contains(cell,'difference')}?set-difference-bg-color" >
            <div th:switch="${cell}">
                <div th:case="'Only in WC'" >
                    <span class="set-green-text-bold" th:text="${cell}">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'New in XLSX'" >
                    <span class="set-red-text-bold" th:text="${cell}">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'No'" >
                    <span class="set-red-text-bold" th:text="${cell}">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div th:case="'Yes'" >
                    <span class="set-green-text-bold" th:text="${cell}">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div th:case="*" >
                    <div th:if="${#strings.contains(cell,'difference')}">
                        <span 
th:text="${#strings.substring(cell,0,#strings.indexOf(cell,'difference'))}"> 
                       </span>                  
                    </div>
                    <div th:unless="${#strings.contains(cell,'difference')}">
                        <span th:text="${cell}"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
            </span>
        </tr>
    </span>
</table>
</div>
 .
 .
```

Recently it is printing all the records on one single page. I am checking for 120 records. How I can split the records 10 or 50 on each page. I am using Thymeleaf.

I have tried to use dandelion datatables, I have added dependencies in pom.xml, create dandelinConfig class etc but still it is not reflecting in result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do  it with using [Dandelion Datatables](https://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.0.1/docs/html/#4-4-changing-display-length).

**Sample usage like this :**

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
                <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
                <artifactId>datatables-spring3</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
                <artifactId>dandelion-thymeleaf</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

And Configuration class is :

```
@Configuration
public class DandelionConfig {


    @Bean
    public DandelionDialect dandelionDialect() {
        return new DandelionDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataTablesDialect dataTablesDialect(){
        return new DataTablesDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter dandelionFilter() {

        return new DandelionFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dandelionServletRegistrationBean() {

        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DandelionServlet(), "/dandelion-assets/*");
    }


}
```

The  you should add dandelion folder under  resources folder : **/resources/dandelion/**. And then create **/resources/dandelion/sample.json** file like below :

```
{
  "bundle" : "custom",
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "bootstrap4-datatables-css",
      "type": "css",
      "locations": {
        "classpath": "static/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "jquery-datatables-js",
      "type": "js",
      "locations": {
        "classpath": "static/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "bootstrap4-datatables-js",
      "type": "js",
      "locations": {
        "classpath": "static/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"
      }
    },

    }
  ]
}
```

and create **/resources/dandelion/dandelion.properties** file :

```
components.standalone=ddl-dt
bundle.includes=custom
```

add aplication properties file `components.standalone = ddl-dt`

.Finally example html file :

```
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:dt="http://www.thymeleaf.org/dandelion/datatables"
    >
 <table id="paging-simple" dt:table="true" dt:pagingType="simple" class="display">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Id</th>
                 <th>Firstname</th>
                 <th>Lastname</th>
                 <th>City</th>
                 <th>Mail</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr th:each="person : ${persons}">
                 <td th:text="${person?.id}">1</td>
                 <td th:text="${person?.firstName}">John</td>
                 <td th:text="${person?.lastName}">Doe</td>
                 <td th:text="${person?.address?.town?.name}">Nobody knows!</td>
                 <td th:text="${person?.mail}">john@doe.com</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
```

.Finally if you want to add pagination your project you will do it ajax request.Detail is [Dandelion Datatables Ajax](https://dandelion.github.io/components/datatables/1.0.1/docs/html/#8-ajax)

Comment: it will be work but you should add dandelion  dataTables config in your project.

Comment: I have added: <dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.dandelion</groupId>
     <artifactId>datatables-thymeleaf</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1</version>
  </dependency> in pom.xml.

Comment: I made a detailed example

Comment: I have made all the changes according to you have specified.. but the result is still not showing.. I have not added custom-datatables.js.

Comment: remove  custom-datatables.js block from json and try again.

Comment: Removed custom-datatables.js. Still its not working.

Comment: Error is not there but the all the records are displaying on same page.

Comment: [All example  here](https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion-datatables-samples/tree/master/datatables-thymeleaf-starter)

Answer (score 0):

im using springboot, java, thymeleaf, foundation(js) and mysql, idontknow about dandelion, but with spring Pageable i can do this

```
public String listadoProductos(Pageable pageable, Model model) {
if(pageable.getPageSize() > PAGE_SIZE_INITIAL) {
  pageable = new PageRequest(0,PAGE_SIZE_INITIAL);
}
Page<Productos> productos = productosRepository.findByEnabled(true, pageable);//trae todos los productos habilitados
model.addAttribute("productos", productos);
modelPaginacion(model, productos, pageable.getPageNumber());

return tiendaFolder+"listaProductos";}
```

and with thyeleaf and foundation do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul class="paginacion text-center">
        <li class="previous"  th:if="${previo}">
            <a th:href="@{/tienda/productos/admin?page={pa}&size={ps}(pa=${paginaActual-1},ps=${size})}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="previa" th:if="${previo}">
            <a th:href="@{/tienda/productos/admin?page={pa}&size={ps}(pa=${paginaActual-1},ps=${size})}" th:text="${paginaActual-1}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="actual" th:text="${paginaActual}">
        </li>
        <li class="siguiente" th:if="${siguiente}">
            <a th:href="@{/tienda/productos/admin?page={pa}&size={ps}(pa=${paginaActual+1},ps=${size})}" th:text="${paginaActual+1}"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="next" th:if="${siguiente}">
            <a th:href="@{/tienda/productos/admin?page={pa}&size={ps}(pa=${paginaActual+1},ps=${size})}"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

is only the block o number of pages